# Android - How To Start New Activity From an Instance

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, instance

i'm new in Android developing. 
I've to start a new Activity. Commonly, i would write the following code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
Activity1.this.startActivity(i);
```

but now i need to start a new activity from an instance of that activity (because i don't want to start a generic activity of that type, i need to call his constructor to define his attributes). Something like this:

```
Activity2 instance = new Activity2(parameters);
Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, instance);
Activity1.this.startActivity(i);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: "(because i don't want to start a generic activity of that type, i need to call his constructor to define his attributes)" -- that is not possible in Android.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're better off to add a bundle to your intent, and read the info out that. You pass your parameters with that bundle.

example:

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, BlipImageSender.class);
    Bundle paramets = new Bundle();

 paramets.putString("YOUR_PARAM_IDENT","your_parameter_value");

 myIntent.putExtras(paramets);
 this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

and in your class:

```
String your_param_value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("YOUR_PARAM_IDENT");
```

Comment: thank you very much nanne, it's so different from classic Java! However i get a NullPointerException using the "sendInfo.getString(key)" in the OnCreate method of my class... i solved by replacing it with "(String)this.getIntent().getExtras().get(key)"

Comment: You're absolutely right! sorry about that, I renamed some var's to make it more readable and skipped some decalrations, and that went a bit too 'well'. I'll fix the answer for later generations :)

Comment: thank you :D it works also with "this.getIntent().getStringExtra(key)"

Comment: I fail to see how that answers the concerns of the OP. What is most surprising the OP accepted the answer. There is communication that is missing.